# Global CommandBar for XAML Windows Universal application

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, app.xaml

In Windows and Windows Phone 8.1 one could define a global appbar in your app.xaml and then reference this appbar in your page to get it added to your page. You would then have only need to implement the XAML once and events once.

I'm struggling to find content on how to manage this correctly with Windows Universal applications. One doesn't have access to the Microsoft.Phone.Shell in the app.xaml anymore due to the the Universal application spin.

Can someone please advise the best way to implement the above global commandbar.

Many thanks.
Dave

Comment: Consider a different approach - Define a master page with a `Frame` and the global `CommandBar`. The `Frame` takes care of the page navigation.

Comment: @JustinXL Many thanks. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The Global Command refers to normal Command Bar?
Here with my code that you can use in Windows/Windows Phone/UWP

```
<Page.BottomAppBar    >
        <CommandBar  x:Name="appBar" IsSticky="False" >
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands  >
                <AppBarButton  Label="Remove ads" Icon="Cancel"  Click="Show_Click" />
                 <AppBarButton  Label="Refresh" Icon="Refresh"  Click="Refresh_Click" />
                <AppBarButton Label="Share" Icon="ReShare" Click="Share_Click"/> 
                 <AppBarButton Label="Review" Icon="LikeDislike" Click="Review_Click"/> 

                <!--<AppBarButton Label="Recommend" Icon="AllApps" Click="AllApps_Click"/>--> 
            </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
             <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="AllApps" Label="Recommend" Click="AllApps_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Comment" Label="Feedback" Click="Feedback_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```